# Use $resource return value inside custom parser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource, angular-directive

I am working on an angular directive which implements a parser to validate the current input by hitting the server, server returns a status in true/false which I have to use to:

1. Make the model Invalid
2. Set the model value to 'undefined' when it's invalid

I have accomplished 1. above by using $setValidity, but having problem in 2. because I need to use the status returned by the server to the $parser function, but since I have to wait for the server response, return statement inside callback is of no use.

```
app.directive('testDir', ['$resource',function($resource){

return{
  restrict:'A',
  require:'ngModel',
  scope:{},
  link:function(scope,element, attr,ngModel){
    ngModel.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

    var req=$resource('data.json');
    var modelval='123';
    req.get({},function(result){
      ngModel.$setValidity('id',result.status);
      //ngModel.$setViewValue(result.name);
      console.log(result.name);
      modelval=result.status?inputValue:undefined;
      return modelval; // this doesn't work
     });
    return modelval; // executes before reading the JSON so always '123'
    });
  }
};
```

I feel I'm missing on some very basic JS since we can't return from inside of a function to outer function, but couldn't figure out a solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iqd5BAkrm6QIUxIIhbzn)

Answer (score 0):

`$resource` is a factory and much like `$http`, it can return a `$promise`.  Therefore, when you are returning the variable `modelval`, you are returning it before the promise has been returned to update this variable.  You should do the following:

```
 var req=$resource('data.json');
 var modelval='123';
 req.get({}).$promise.then(function(result){
   ngModel.$setValidity('id',result.status);
   //ngModel.$setViewValue(result.name);
   console.log(result.name);
   modelval=result.status?inputValue:undefined;
   return modelval; // this will update if the request is a success
 }, function(error){
    //error handling should go here
});
return modelval; // this will still execute before reading the JSON so will always return '123'
});
```

If you are wanting to use the return of the promise in another place, you should consider looking into using `$q`.  This is another service that allows you to defer resolved or rejected promises to be used elsewhere.

Comment: your solution doesn't seem to work, although the callback gets executed properly, but the return value doesn't update the model and even though `result.status` is false, I am expecting the final model value to be 'undefined' instead of '123'. I have updated the plunk with your solution. Please take a look.